# Using onBlur to set focus in a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, onblur, onfocus

I've attached an `onBlur` event handler in a React component in which the logic sets the focus back to the target element (and writing this in TypeScript).

```
emailBlur(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    e.currentTarget.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
    // re-ordering these statements makes no difference
}
```

This is bound

```
<input type="email" onBlur={this.emailBlur} />
```

Furthermore, the constructor contains

```
this.emailBlur = this.emailBlur.bind(this);
```

But the focus never gets set - if I click from the target element to another element, the focus never goes back to the target element.

Why isn't the focus being set back to the target element?

Comment: What version of react.js do you use? Do you have some errors in a  console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using e.currentTarget and a timeout like this?

```
e.preventDefault();
const target = e.currentTarget;
setTimeout(
    function () {
        target.focus();
    },
    5
);
```

Comment: You probably don't even need `5` delay in the timeout. The delay argument of `setTimeout` could be omitted just to make sure the function gets called in next tick.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't the focus being set back to the target element?

Use `setTimeout` so the `blur` completes before you `focus` again

Comment: If I wrap it in a `setTimeout` with a 500ms timer I then get the exception "TypeError: e.currentTarget.focus is not a function".  If I switch the statement to use `e.target...` or `e.relatedTarget...` then I'm told that `focus` is not a function or property.

Comment: Also, why do I need to wait for `blur` to complete if I'm using `e.preventDefault`?